# Why design view is not visible?

Tags: android-studio

[image: 1]

Android studio electric Eel 2022.1.1

I am trying to go to design view but there is no design view option...i am new to it. I don't know anything

Comment: Can you post a proper screenshot instead of a picture of your monitor please?